Can't write with any ibus input method (e.g. Bangla) in obsidian
I have installed ibus-avro in my ubuntu desktop 24.04 lts version . It works on any other app like terminal , libreoffice , browser but don't work in obsidian app.
I have create a topic in obsidian forum but seems no one is interested. Link here

Is obsidian an electron app? Can you provide more information about it? How did you install obsidian?

Most likely, the problem is not specific to avro, but any ibus generated input

Seems to be a common issue related to obsidian https://forum.obsidian.md/t/obsidian-cannot-change-to-different-language/84473

yes electron app

from ubuntu app store

It seems to be a snap-only issue. Most likely, as snap apps are not native packages, Obsidian (installed as snap) cannot get input from ibus.
First, backup your notes and remove the Obsidian snap package from Ubuntu app store.
Next, install Obsidian deb package from its official website https://obsidian.md/download.
E.g., here is the download link for v1.6.7 https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-releases/releases/download/v1.6.7/obsidian_1.6.7_amd64.deb.
Afterward, install the Obsidian .deb package (here is how to install .deb packages in Ubuntu 24.04).
Note: You may need to disable Ubuntu's new AppArmor user namespace creation restrictions for the .deb package to work.
Input from ibus-avro works. Check image below.


Thanks . I'll let you know after trying

And it woked well . So the problem was snap related.

@RaihanurRahman If it worked, you can click on the checkmark on the left side of my answer to accept it. Then, it will help future users decide that it was useful.

marked your answer

@RaihanurRahman That did not work. This is how to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/281134

Thanks again I didn't know that
